# map does not zoom to a feature - openlayer's zoomToExtend

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm using Geoserver 2.1.3 and openlayers 2.12. I created a vector layer and I implemented a "Search" functionality using CQL. After the CQL search, I succesfully render new features on the layer. And then I use the following code, so the map will zoom to the new features.

```
map.zoomToExtent(myLayer.getDataExtent());
```

If I use this code with the other vector layers, works just fine. But for this particular layer, does not zoom to the new features. Keeps zooming on a certain, irrelevant area.

Any tips/hints?

Thanks

Comment: What is different between the layers you can zoom to and the one you cannot zoom to (e.g. coordinate system, data type)?

Comment: Are both the layer and your map in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Be sure to clear myLayer calling removeAllFeatures before adding new features from CQL filter. You should try to iterate all features inside the layer and create a bbox from each feature extents, so you can manually check the actual extent of the layer.

Comment: @artwork21 All layers I tested this code are vector layers, containing features. The other two layers render html5's geolocation and geocoding. myLayer renders features after CQL search, getting data from Geoserver and postGIS

 - Devdatta,  Yes, they all are EPSG900913

 - D_Guidi, Of course I clear the layer from the features. Manually checking the layer, good idea, thanks, will do